# Neatly tab multiple items

Tags: tabbing

From the code below, I have the items tabbed.  I wanted to know if the colon ":" can also be aligined to get a neater look?

[image]

Here the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
  \hspace{3cm} \= \hspace{3.5cm} \= \hspace{3.9cm}\kill
  % \> for next tab, \\ for new line...
  $\mathcal{L}:Phase~Noise$ \> $F:\text{\emph{Noise Factor}}$ \> $k:Boltzmann's~Constant$\\
   $P_{in}: Input~Power$\>  $P_{sav}: Average~Power$ \>  $P_{sig}$: \emph{Signal Power}\\
    $\omega_{o}:\text{\emph{Carrier Freq}}$ \> $\omega_{m}:\text{\emph{Offset Freq}}$ \> $\omega_{c}:\text{\emph{Active Device Flicker Corner}}$ \\
    $T:Temp(^{\circ}K)$ \> $Q_{unl}:Unloaded~ Q$ \>$W_{e}: \text{\emph{Reactive energy stored in $L$ and $C$}}$
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can add tab stops at the colons too, but probably it is better to use a tabular environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a `tabular` environment.

[image]

As you can tell, I didn't remove the `\emph` instructions. I don't understand why they're there, though. If it were my table, I'd remove the `\emph` directives. I also have some misgivings about writing "degree Kelvin" -- I seem to remember being taught that it's just "Kelvin" when indicating a temperature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{L@{\,:\,\,}l} @{}}
\mathcal{L} & Phase~Noise & F & \emph{Noise Factor} &  k & Boltzmann's~Constant\\
P_{in} & Input~Power & P_{sav} & Average~Power & P_{sig} & \emph{Signal Power}\\
\omega_{o} & \emph{Carrier Freq} & \omega_{m} & \emph{Offset Freq} & \omega_{c} & \emph{Active Device Flicker Corner} \\
T & Temp ($^{\circ}$K) & Q_{unl} & Unloaded $Q$ & W_{e} & \emph{Reactive energy stored in $L$ and $C$} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```